# Swift 2.1 Closure

Tags: swift, swift2

At first, I apologize for my English!
Please help me detect when I was wrong.

```
let arrayInt = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]

func myF(array: [Int], cl:(n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool) -> Int {

    var number : Int

    for value in array {
        if cl(n1: number, n2: value) {
            number = value
        }
    }

    return number

}

myF(arrayInt, { cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in 
    return n1 < n2
})
```

The function takes an array of Int and closure returns Int. Closure should take two Int numbers and return Bool yes or no. It is necessary to walk in a loop through the array and compare elements of array with variable using closure . If closure returns yes, you write the value of the array into variable. At the end of the function returns the variable. We need find max and min value in array.

I have 3 issue:

1. consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
2. expected expression
3. contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored

Please don't proposed me use method "sort()". I am learning of "closure".

Comment: So what for issues do you have? "var number : Int" - here you should initialize your variable – var number = 0

Comment: I have 3 issue:

1. consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
2. expected expression
3. contextual type for closure argument list expects 2 arguments, which cannot be implicitly ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace:

```
myF(arrayInt, { cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
```

by:

```
myF(arrayInt, cl: { (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
```

because cl is the parameter name and all included in { } is the closure.
Second initialize number in myF function replacing:

```
var number : Int
```

by:

```
var number = array[0]
```

if the goal of the closure is to find max or min value.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to initialize your `number` variable: `var number : Int` -> `var number = 0`

Second, the function call with closure is not correct. There are several ways to call a closure:

```
let y = myF(arrayInt, cl: { (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool in
    return n1 < n2
})
```

or

```
let x = myF(arrayInt) { (n1, n2) -> Bool in
    return n1 < n2
}
```

or even

```
let z = myF(arrayInt) { n1, n2 in
    return n1 < n2
}
```

and

```
let w = myF(arrayInt) { $0 < $1 }
```

[This link](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) and [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) should help you

Full code sample:

```
let arrayInt = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4]

func myF(array: [Int], cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int) -> Bool) -> Int {
    var number = 0
    for i in array {
        if cl(n1: number, n2: i) {
            number = i
        } 
    }
    return number
}


let x = myF(arrayInt) { (n1, n2) -> Bool in
    return n1 < n2
}
```

Comment: Your answer has zero text. It is hard to see what was wrong with his code and where you fixed it, without going through both line by line. Perhaps some explanation would be good.

Comment: @NicolasMiari, thank you for your remark. Added some description.

Comment: Thanks, Andrey!
But why in body closure we deleted call own closure? I mean this string: "cl: (n1: Int, n2: Int)" which we changed to this "(n1, n2)"?

Comment: @Roman, just edited my answer. Your call was simply syntactically not correct.

Comment: Thank you again! 
Have a nice day!